# Laravel 5.6 how to show few pictures in one article

Tags: laravel, object, laravel-blade

Good afternoon,

I am working on the blog where I have detail of the article and want to show few pictures.

What I am getting at the moment:
[image]

As you can see I am getting the content and after the content pictures. Here is also the code of the blade.

```
<div class="container">
      @foreach($articles as $article)
        <article>
          <h1 class="title is-1"><a href="{{route('show', $article->id)}}">{{$article->title}}</a></h1>
            @foreach($article->images as $image)
              <figure class="image is-128x128">
                <img src="{{$image->path}}" alt="{{$image->title}}">
              </figure>
            @endforeach
          <p>{{$article->content}}</p>
        </article>
      @endforeach
    </div>
```

Because I am getting a object I cannot split the pictures.

[image].

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Very simple. As you can see at the pictures. I need text, picture, text. Now I have only text and pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was rather hard to figure out what you want, but I'm quite sure I finally got the *question*.

What you wanna do is something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  @foreach($articles as $article)
    <article>
      <h1 class="title is-1"><a href="{{route('show', $article->id)}}">{{$article->title}}</a></h1>
      @if(count($article->images) > 0)
        <figure class="image is-128x128">
          <img src="{{$article->images->first()->path}}" alt="{{$article->images->first()->title}}">
        </figure>
      @endif
      <p>{{$article->content}}</p>
      @if(count($article->images) > 1)
        @foreach($article->images->slice(1) as $image)
          <figure class="image is-128x128">
            <img src="{{$image->path}}" alt="{{$image->title}}">
          </figure>
        @endforeach
      @endif
    </article>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

This will not only give you **headline > image 1 > content > remaining images**, it will also make sure you only print images when there are actually some available. The `$article->images->slice(1)` within the second `@if()` will ensure we are not using the first image a second time.

Comment: Thank you very much this solution is working. I need to read documentation!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure `$image->path` is the correct to the image file (if it's an url, skip this point). 
   You can check by echoing it or just dd($image->path).
2. For the image to be accessed, it needs to be on the public folder of laravel

If you wish to have the files in the storage folder and have it accessed publicly, you'll need to create a symlink

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem

Comment: ohhh I see. Do you think I should not t use mysql for saving the path?